# How to do Excel looping using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a tool to build a stored procedure based on the available prices getting directly from vendor. As per the attached snap, I paste all the rics (identifier) under column I and put the number of days in cell B2 (let's say I am looking for last 300 days of historical prices for STIM.OQ, VOD.L (vodafone) and AAPL.OQ (Apple Inc).

Currently this tool only fetches the prices for a single ric based on the cell value A2, I wanted to put this in a loop so that whatever rics I paste in column I go through that loop and the code should copy the stored procedure from column F and append it to a new single sheet for each of the rics.

Note: the stored procedure takes the value from cell B8, D8 and E8

[image]

Comment: Please phrase your question in the form of a question.

Comment: have made the changes

Comment: can anyone pls help or guide

Comment: @Naina do you already have a Sub/Function defined that takes the value from A2 and creates a new sheet with relevant data?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row` to find the last row and then loop through starting at row 2.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateProcs()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsRic As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long, n As Long, i As Integer
    Dim ric As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' as appropriate
    n = ws.Range("B2").Value ' days

    ' loop through rics in col I
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To iLastRow
        ric = ws.Cells(r, "I")
        ws.Range("A2").Value2 = ric

        ' create sheet
        Set wsRic = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        wsRic.Name = ric

        ' copy data
        wsRic.Range("A1:A" & n).Value2 = ws.Range("F8").Resize(n).Value2
        i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox i & " sheets created", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: @Naina What was the  problem ?

Comment: i was taking the prices from TR feed so that wasn't auto refreshing and giving same value for all the underlyings then i used Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorksheet" to made it run

Comment: the last thing which is bothering me is i am not able to clear content for this range (B6:F6).End(xldown).clear as there are some blank cells in between

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InsertSeveralSpots").Range("B6:F5000").ClearContents  - worked !